# Reformat date in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a column of many dates which are a plain text format, not set as date fields. I am gong to import it into a database but I need to change the format of the date.

It is stored as **21.09.1942** and I need it in the format of **1942/09/21** for the database. I have tried `=TEXT(DATEVALUE(G2), "yyyy/mm/dd")` but get invalid value error.

I was going to put the formula into a new column beside the date and drag it down to include all records. Some rows do not have a date so I want to output a blank field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you computer's regional settings is set to UK, you can do a simple Find+Replace on `.` and replace by `/`. You then only have to format it as `yyyy/mm/dd` through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> as `yyyy/mm/dd`.

---

If your computer's regional settings is set to US, the above will mess up your dates. Some will be kept as text in the form of `21/09/1942`, and others such as `01.06.2000` (`dd.mm.yyyy`) will get converted to `06/01/2000` (excel treats the previous date as `mm.dd.yyyy`).

Your next solution for this would be to manually extract the dates and concatenate it. Since your computer is in US in this case, you can use:

```
=(mid(E2,3,2)&"/"&left(E2,2)&"/"&right(E2,4))*1
```

This first converts `21.09.1942` to a text form of `09/21/1942` and multiplying by one converts it to date. You then format the column through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> as  `yyyy/mm/dd`.

Comment: the actual fields are text so my I think my regional settings dont effect the dates as it see it as just text. I think your solution of extracting each element and swapping them around will work. I will try it and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @KeithPower Believe me the regional settings mess things up! I've dealt with converting dates like those a lot and it's was a headache when my settings were on US. Had to change to UK because I can't understand how dates can be in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

Comment: that I changed it slightly to =(RIGHT(G11,4)&"/"&MID(G11,4,2)&"/"&LEFT(G11,2)) as i wan to leave as text because it is going to be imported to a database. One last question for the field that do no have a date record I get //. Is there a way to output nothing?

Comment: @KeithPower You can always wrap an `IF` around the formula like so: `=IF(G11="","",RIGHT(G11,4)&"/"&MID(G11,4,2)&"/"&LEFT(G11,2))`. Good luck with the import! I get the tendency to format the columns in excel itself before importing in Access. Bad experiences ^^;